# Member access differences

Tags: c++, operators, operator-precedence

can someone tell me what is the different between `(*ptr).field` and `ptr->field`?
I know it connect somehow to static and dynamic linking, but i dont know what is it.
can someone tell me the differnet and give me an example?

edit:
 if i have this code:

```
Point p;       //point is a class that derive from class shape 
Shape *s=&p; 
               //there is a diffrence if i write:

(*s).print();  //print is virtual func
s->print();    // the answers will not be the same, why?
```

TNX!

Comment: Did you mean `(*ptr).field` or `*ptr.field`? If you really meant `*ptr.field`, then these two forms just have nothing in common at all, which makes the question virtually meaningless.

Comment: From your edit: The answer will be the same. See below.

Comment: I don't know what "answers" you are referring to in your code sample, but in your code sample both calls will do *exactly the same thing*. There's absolutely no difference between them.

Comment: @aharont: The code you posted doesn't illustrate a difference. Please post a complete minimal test case, which should be compilable as-is. It should thus include minimal definitions for `Shape` and `Point`. It should also probably be a new question, as the new question is different from "What's the difference between (*ptr).field and ptr->field?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it has nothing to do with static or dynamic linking 
both expressions will return the value of ptr.field

the ptr->field form is an abbreviated syntax for accessing a member directly from a pointer

**UPDATE**:  it  occurred to me that your original intent was not linking but **binding** 
if this indeed was what you were aiming to then there is **static binding** and **dynamic binding**
which have some relation to the -> operator  [see here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Programming/Classes/Polymorphism)

Comment: Yes, but abbreviated for (*ptr).fld, not for *ptr.field.

Comment: It's important to note that these are NOT necessarily equivalent, due to the possibility to overload operator* and operator-> in C++!

Comment: @Hostile Fork:  Which is why, in some shops, C++ code review sessions should include electroshock therapy machines.

Comment: glad we pieced it together at the end ;-)

Answer (score 7):

This has nothing to do with static or dynamic linking.

See [C++'s operator precedence](http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/operator_precedence).  The `.` has a lower precedence than `*`, so there's actually quite a difference between `*ptr.fld` and `ptr->fld`.  For example, the following code demonstrates:

```
#include <iostream>

struct foo {
  int f;
};

int main() {
  struct foo *p = new struct foo;
  p->f = 42;
  std::cout << p->f << std::endl;
  std::cout << (*p).f << std::endl;
  // The following will not compile
  // std::cout << *p.f << std::endl;
}
```

As John Knoeller points out, `ptr->fld` is syntactic sugar for `(*(ptr)).fld`, but is not the same as `*ptr.fld`, which would actually evaluate to `*(ptr.fld)`, probably not what you want.

You'd use `ptr->fld` when you have a pointer to a structure and want to access a field contained therein.  `(*(ptr)).fld` means the same thing but is not as tidy.  You'd use `*strct.fld` when you have a structure, not a pointer to a structure, that contains a field (`fld`) which is a pointer you want to dereference.  The case of `ptr->fld` is shown above.  The case of `*strct.fld` could be used with the following structure:

```
struct foo {
  int *fld;
}

struct foo f;
f.fld = new int;
*f.fld = 42;
```

Comment: As pointed out by outis, ptr->field is actually syntatic sugar for (*(ptr)).field, not for (*ptr).field.  Ooops.  Fixed.

Comment: Since `ptr` is an identifier, `(*ptr).field` is fine. Still, it's good to point out the general case.

Comment: The OP confirmed that he actually meant `(*ptr).field`. I edited the question.

Answer (score 2):

Static linking is the result of the linker copying all library routines used in the program into the executable image. This may require more disk space and memory than dynamic linking, but is both faster and more portable, since it does not require the presence of the library on the system where it is run.

Dynamic linking is accomplished by placing the name of a sharable library in the executable image. Actual linking with the library routines does not occur until the image is run, when both the executable and the library are placed in memory. An advantage of dynamic linking is that multiple programs can share a single copy of the library.

But it is unrelated to pointer indirection you've mentioned -- in fact, those two expressions are identical.

Comment: Not quite.  ptr->field is identical to (*ptr).field, not to *ptr.field.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that by `*ptr.field` you meant `(*ptr).field`.

As far as only built-in operators are considered, there's no difference between the two. And no, it has nothing to do with and "static" or "dynamic" linking, whatever is implied by these terms.

The only potential difference between the two is that in `ptr->field` variant `->` is an overloadable operator in C++, while in the `(*ptr).field` variant only `*` is overloadable, while `.` is not.

Also, some differences between these two methods of member access existed in very archaic versions of C language (CRM C), but I doubt anyone cares about those today.

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with linking.

```
ptr->fld
```

is merely shorthand for

```
(*ptr).fld
```

It's pure syntactic sugar ;)

Comment: In particular, see § 5.2.5.3 of the C++ standard.

Comment: § 5.2.5 3 If E1 has the type “pointer to classX,” then the expression E1->E2 is converted to the equivalent form 
(*(E1)).E2; the remainder of 5.2.5 will address only the first option (dot).

Comment: @outis: The part you quoted desribes the behavior of the *built-in* operator `->`. Don't forget that `->` in C++ does not necessarily refer to the built-in operator. It can also be overloaded by the user. The OP did not say that `ptr` is of raw pointer type.

Comment: I didn't forget that. Since the quotation states that the equivalence applies when `ptr` is a pointer, I didn't bother to say it in my own words.

Answer (score 1):

As long as `ptr` is a pointer, the two are equivalent once properly parenthesized (as others have said). If `ptr` is an object, rather than a pointer, they might be different depending on definitions for `operator*` and `operator->` (if any) from the object's class or ancestors.

Comment: ok, if i have this code:
Point p;//point is a class that derive from class shape
Shape *s=&p;

there is a diffrence if i write (*s).print();//print is virtual func
to s->print();

the answers will not be the same, why?

Answer (score 1):

The form -> is just shorthand for de-refrencing the pointer and accessing the member.

```
(*ptr).field;
// Equiv to 
ptr->field;
```

One good reason for using -> is that when you are following a chain:

```
int x = (*(*(*(*ptr).field1).field2).field3).field4;
// Equiv to 
int y = ptr->field1->field2->field3->field4;
```

The second one becomes much more readable.

As for the second part of your question.
I find it really easy to just nock up an example.

```
#include <iostream>

class Shape
{
    public:   virtual ~Shape()        {}
              virtual void Print()    {std::cout << "Shape\n";}
};
class Point: public Shape
{
    public:   virtual void Print()    {std::cout << "Point\n";}
};

int main ()
{
    Point   p;
    Shape*  s = &p;

    s->Print();
    (*s).Print();
}

> vi x.cpp
> g++ x.cpp
> ./a.exe
Point
Point
```

As you can see the result is the same in both situations.

When you call a method via a pointer or a reference the virtual call mechanism will be invoked. The star operator (AKA derefence operator) returns a reference to an object (it does not actually de-reference the object). So when it is used to call a method the virtual call mechanism will be invoked and the most derived version of the method called.

Comment: ok, tanks, although my DR. said there is some different, but i cant remember what...

Comment: There is no difference between (*ptr)->f1 and ptr->f1. That is defined by the standard. If we move to virtual functions. There re situations where the virtal call mechanism will not be used, but this is not one of them.

Comment: so what is the case that the virtal call mechanism will not be used?

Comment: When you name it explicitly (I forget the term). But a method in Point can call Shape::Print() or Point::Print() to get a specific version of the method.

Comment: Are you thinking of "qualified name"? Or perhaps "explicit scope resolution"?

Answer (score 0):

They are both the same.
`*ptr.field` dereferences the variable `ptr` then returns the value of member `field`.

The `->` operator is shorthand notation for the above.

Comment: Actually, `*ptr.field` is evaluated as `*(ptr.field)`, not `(*ptr).field`.